# Does diff$(M)$ act transitively on the set of integrable $G$-structures?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact manifold and diff$(M)$ its diffeomorphism group. Let $G$ be a Lie subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

In general, the topology of a manifold may prevent it from having an integrable $G$-structure. An easy example is $M=S^2$ and $G=O(2)$. An integrable $O(2)$-structure is a flat Riemannian metric. Such a metric cannot exist due to the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.

So suppose that $M$ has at least one integrable $G$-structure. Call it $k$. Is the set of *all* integrable $G$-structures on $M$ the orbit of $k$ under the action of diff$(M)$?

Comment: Surely not; wouldn't that imply that e.g. the isomorphism type of a complex manifold is completely determined by its underlying smooth manifold?

Comment: Consider $G=SL(n,R)$. Then $G$-structures are volume forms. On a compact manifold, the volume of the manifold is an invariant of the $G$-structure, even after diffeomorphism. So the answer is no. Similarly for the symplectic group. Ever for a flat Riemannian metric, on a torus, there are different volumes and different sets of lengths of closed geodesics. But in general, no one knows what the diffeomorphism invariants of flat $G$-structures are.

Comment: Just a comment on terminology:  You should be careful about using the term 'integrable $G$-structure', since this means different things to different authors.  For example, while Guillemin, in his papers, takes 'integrable $G$-structure' to be synonymous with 'locally flat $G$-structure', this conflicts with an older usage by authors such as Chern, for whom an integrable $G$-structure is one whose intrinsic torsion functions are constant (not necessarily zero).  Thus, for example, for Chern, a contact structure is an integrable $G$-structure while it is not for Guillemin.